# Couchbase NodeJs SDK bucket.insert not returning value

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am having a wired issue, when i do a insert / create new doc in my bucket it creates it successful and it returns the CAS value for new doc but if i want to access the actual result.value i get undefined. I can access result.cas. As i need to return the id which was created when creating the item in couchbase i am wondering how i can do that without making a separate call

```
var initialLead = function(doc){
bucket.insert('leads::' + uuidv4(), leadbase(doc), function(err, result) {
if (!err) {
  console.log("stored document successfully. Value is", result.value);
} else {
  console.error("Couldn't store document: %j", err);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In couchbase, the ID (a.k.a. key) is created by you, so you have it there to return.  The CAS is just an opaque value associated with that particular mutation.

From you code example, your ID/key is:

`'leads::' + uuidv4()`

Comment: That’s the id of the doc but I als assign a id for I create in contact.  As I won’t know that I’d I would have to pass the id around or get it from the doc after get doc by id. For some reason I thought it can return the just inserted doc, was hoping to save a extra query